# Postgresql create function syntax error near BEGIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core, plpgsql

This is the function I'm trying to execute via migration script.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(key1 text)
RETURNS void AS $$ 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1(c1) VALUES($1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The above script executes successfully, but when I tried to with a .NET Core idempotent migration script it gives an error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"`

This is the migration script.

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM __EFMigrationsHistory WHERE "MigrationId" = 'migrationid') THEN
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(key1 text)
    RETURNS void AS $$ 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO table1(c1) VALUES($1);
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
    END IF;
END $$;
```

I also tried adding EXECUTE still same error.

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM __EFMigrationsHistory WHERE "MigrationId" = 'migrationid') THEN
    EXECUTE('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(key1 text)
    RETURNS void AS $$ 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO table1(c1) VALUES($1);
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE ''plpgsql'';');
    END IF;
END $$;
```

How can I create a SQL statement to create/replace the function by checking the migrationhistory table?

Comment: Change the `$$` dollar quote to something else both places inside the function, e.g. `$other$`.  The `$$` on the line, `RETURNS void AS $$`, is terminating the `DO $$` quote.

Comment: Why the do block at all? `create or replace` will always work unless you change the signature or return type. Also (unrelated): the language name is an identifier. Do not enclose it in single quotes. This is deprecated and might not work in future versions. Use `language plpgsql` instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The do begin statements are generated by the migration utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser is getting confused by the repetitive usage of dollar quotes. Just give one of them an alias and it should work, e.g.

```
DO $body$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM __EFMigrationsHistory WHERE "MigrationId" = 'migrationid') THEN
    EXECUTE('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(key1 text)
    RETURNS void AS $$ 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO table1(c1) VALUES($1);
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE ''plpgsql'';');
    END IF;
END $body$;
```